# Create php array from one of all column that retrieve from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I am a newbie on PHP,MySQL and HTML.

I have one question about php array.

I create MySQL query that joins 2 tables in php. From this join, I will get information about one product, but have multiple JIG.

```
$sql = "SELECT product.product_number,product.product_name,product.product_jitqty,product.product_desc,jit.jit_number,jit.jit_name,jit.jit_drawer,jit.jit_port,jit.jit_specpath 
FROM product 
JOIN production_jit 
ON production_jit.product_number = product.product_number 
JOIN jit 
ON jit.jit_number = production_jit.jit_number
WHERE product.product_number = '$productnumber'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 

    {   }
```

from above query, I will get result like picture below.
[image]

So I want to create an array for column `jit.jit_number`. for easy to transfer both or only one data to another page.

I have tried below code.

```
        $sql = "SELECT product.product_number,product.product_name,product.product_jitqty,product.product_desc,jit.jit_number,jit.jit_name,jit.jit_drawer,jit.jit_port,jit.jit_specpath 
            FROM product 
            JOIN production_jit 
            ON production_jit.product_number = product.product_number 
            JOIN jit 
            ON jit.jit_number = production_jit.jit_number
            WHERE product.product_number = '$productnumber'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    ?>

    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 

    {   

    $jig = array ($row['jit_number']);

    echo "This is JIG " . $jig[0] . ", " . $jig[1] . ".";

    }
```

But the result is like picture below.

[image]

Can anyone help me? So if I want to transfer both data to another page, I just can use `$jig[0]` and `$jig[1]`. Or anyone can advise me the better way to transfer multiple data form mysql to another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve, but `$jig` is not going to have two indices because `$row['jit_number']` ist just a number itself. If you're trying to store all jit_numbers in a separate array, you could try something like this:

```
$numbers = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{   
    $numbers[] = $row['jit_number'];
}
```

You shall also try to prevent MySQL injection, `WHERE product.product_number = '$productnumber'";` is rather horrible from a security point of view. Using a prepared statement or at least some sanitization / escaping is recommendable.

Comment: sorry if you not understand. i give you example that i want.
i retrieve data from mysql that product number is "123456". for that product have 2 jig which is "abc" and "def" as figure that i ask above. so i want transfer "abc" and "def" as $jig1 and $jig2 to another page because i want to create validation part. 
what i means with "validation" part is, our operator will scan the jig bar code and on "validation" part i want to make if else statement with like this..[if ($jigcode1==$jig1 && $jigcode2==$jig2 )]. if the jig is correct, our operator will showed our product spec.

Answer (score 1):

Try this->

```
$jig = array();
array_push($jig, $row['jit_number']);
```